# Integrability of $1/(1+|x|)^{p(x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $p(x)$ be a measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $p(x)>1$. Is it true that the function $1/(1+|x|)^{p(x)}$ is integrable on  $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's obvious that there exists $p(x)>1$ such that $$\frac1{(1+|x|)^{p(x)}}=\frac12\frac1{1+|x|}\quad\quad(x\ne0).$$

Comment: It is simple and elegant. But It seems like you are stalking me now :)

Answer (score 5):

$${\bf \text{Hint}}\text{: consider } p(x) = 1 + e^{-|x|}.$$

Comment: Your example works. But I cannot accept an hint as an answer.

Comment: @Josh: You can accept anything you want as an answer. There are no restrictions.

Comment: I give you an hint: I don't like an hint as an answer. You are not writing a book for students. You are on stack exchange. When I was a student they asked me to solve a problem during an examination. I answered: hint: consider... They didn't appreciate. 

Comment: @Josh it's a generally followed idea that when the OP doesn't show much effort into solving their question, to give them assistence but force them to think about the problem a bit.

Comment: @Stella I know what you mean. But this idea is good for students not for stack exchange.  A hint can be given as a comment. My aim was to create a small discussion and new observations about that question and it is what I got from the other answers. That an exponential decay was sufficient was a trivial guess. Now I now that a so fast decay is not necessary and I have learned something.

Comment: @Kosh "But this idea is good for students not for stack exchange." Fascinating. You mention from time to time that you're not  that familiar with MSE. Fine, but that makes it very curious that you continually disagree with people's comments on what's acceptable and what's standard on MSE. What Stella said _is_ a generally accepted policy, _on_ MSE.

Comment: @Kosh No reason to accept the answer if you don't  want to. But your commennt "When I was a student they asked me to solve a problem during an examination. I answered: hint: consider... They didn't appreciate." is just silly, because that's a different _context_. On that exam the point is for you to prove you know how to do the problem. Here the point is not for parsiad to prove he knows how to do the problem, rather he was trying to help you see how to do it. You're supposed to thank him for that, not lecture us on how MSE is supposed to work.

Comment: yikes! so much fuss about a hint you are receiving for free

Answer (score 1):

**It is not true**. To show it, the first thought would be to pick a function $p(x)$ which is $>1$ but decays to $1$ very fast at infinity. As *parsiad* suggests, $p(x)=1+e^{-|x|}$ works nicely, but then we need to prove that $1/(1+|x|)^{1+e^{-|x|}}$ is not integrable, which didn't look friendly enough for me.

The choice $p(x)=1+1/\log(1+|x|)$
also works ---showing that we actually didn't need such a fast decay to $1$---, and can be quickly verified:
\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{dx}{(1+|x|)^{1+\frac{1}{\log(1+|x|)}}}&=2\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x)^{1+\frac{1}{\log(1+x)}}}\\&=\frac{2}{e}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{1+x}=\frac{2}{e}\lim_{x\to+\infty}\log(1+x)=+\infty,
\end{align}
where I've used that $$(1+x)^{1+\frac{1}{\log(1+x)}}=e^{\left(1+\frac{1}{\log(1+x)}\right)\log(1+x)}=e\cdot e^{\log(1+x)}=e(1+x).$$

Comment: Your exponent function is not greater than 1. You must consider something which is asymptotic to 1 around infinity.

Comment: Ooops how silly of mine. I will delete it and see if I can fix it. Thank you for noticing it!@Josh

Comment: @Josh I think it is ok now. Actually this choice of $p(x)$ was already my first guess. I  just thought It was simpler without the '1+' when I was doing the calculations and forgot that it was fundamental.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(x) = 1+1/(|x|+1).$ Then

$$\tag 1 \int_{\mathbb R} \left (\frac{1}{1+|x|}\right)^{p(x)}\, dx  \ge \int_1^\infty \left (\frac{1}{1+x}\right)^{1+1/x}\, dx.$$

Now verify that $(1+x)^{1+1/x} \sim (1+x).$ It follows that the integral on the right of $(1)$ diverges, hence so does the left side of $(1).$.